# EXCEL SQL SELECT won't recognize field names in ThisWorkBook

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm a self taught Excel VBA and SQL user. I'm testing out some simple queries before I add complexity. I must be missing something blindingly obvious here...

I am using an ADO connection to run a SQL SELECT statement on a table in the activeworkbook (ThisWorkBook). The Excel Table is named "tbl_QDB" and is on worksheet "MyQDB". The table starts on cell A1, so there are no blank or populated cells above the Table HeaderRowRange.

I have set up an ADO connection to ThisWorkBook and this is working fine. Here's the code:

```
Sub ConnectionOpen2()

'### UNDER DEVELOPMENT
Dim sconnect As String
Const adUseClient = 3
Const adUseServer = 2
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adOpenKeyset = 1
Const adOpenDynamic = 2

'used to connect to this workbook for SQL runs

On Error GoTo err_OpenConnection2

Set cn2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rec2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rec2.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rec2.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rec2.LockType = adLockOptimistic

datasource = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
             "Data Source=" & datasource & ";" & _
             "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;ReadOnly=False;Imex=0"";"

    cn2.Open sconnect

'etc, etc...

End Sub
```

I can run this simplest basic SELECT query:

```
SQLSTR="SELECT * FROM [MYQDB$]"
rec2.open SQLSTR, cn2
```

This works and produces 10 records i.e. rec2.recordcount=10.

However, if I try this, it errors:

```
SQLSTR="SELECT QID_1 FROM [MYQDB$]"
```

[image]

QID_1 is a valid field in the table on worksheet "MyQDB".
It doesn't change the error if I enclose QID_1 in () or [] or ``
I can even replace the field name with a made up field e.g. DonaldDuck and I get the same error.

Why would the SELECT statement work if I use "*" but not if I use any of the field names in the table? This seems so basic that I feel I must have missed a simple but key point.

I really will appreciate if someone can point out the mistake!

Comment: Why are you trying to *query* an Excel sheet from inside *Excel*? Just load the sheet and read the cells

Comment: `QID_1` isn't a field name. Excel doesn't have fields, it has *cells*. Cell addresses are eg `$A$1`. The error itself means that the query contains parameter specifiers but no parameter value was passed. Most likely Excel confused the unexpected `QID_1` value for a parameter

Comment: Why do you call `QID_1` a field? Excel has rows and columns, not fields. You can *name* specific ranges and treat them as tables in SQL queries. A named cell is still a range, with only 1 row and 1 column. A table is still a named range. Your *query* though targets the entire sheet, not a specific table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - suggest you spend some time trying out this method before commenting on the OP's approach.  There is nothing wrong or odd about what they're doing here.

Comment: @TimWilliams except it's not working. You can't name *Excel columns*. If you define an Excel table, you can use the header names as field names. In order to get something named `QID_1` it would have to be a header of a Table

Comment: The headers are field names in an Excel table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I realize you can't "name" individual columns, but the Excel driver is smart enough to recognize your headers provided (as noted by the OP) your sheet is structured appropriately.  There is no need to make your data a "Table" - the driver will determine the size of your existing data, so a simple "select *  from  [Sheet2$]" will typically succeed.

Answer (score 3):

The SQL should work - if the field exists. Execute the `Select *` and dump the field list:

```
For i = 0 To rec2.Fields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print rec2.Fields(i).Name
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your comments.
That suggestion @FunThomas was an eye opener! The results were F1, F2, F3 etc, so the field names (or column names if you prefer) were not being recognised.

This would explain why, after days of trying to join this table with another in a closed, external workbook, it was not working. SQL error messages can be quite obtuse and were not saying it didn't recognise the field name.

I have now fixed that issue. Here's what I can tell / warn others:

1. I started this table with rows above the header. In 2 of those cells
   above I recorded the last connection time and status to another
   workbook table. I realised before that these extra rows, with data
   populated in ANY cell above the headers, were causing problems with
   SQL. Despite having my data in an Excel Table, the SQL "engine" for
   Excel looks at the sheet, i.e. [MYQDB$] where the data is stored
   (although I am aware that you can specify a sheet and range, but
   cannot use the actual table name as the range).
2. It is ok to have blank rows above the table headerrowrange. So, I
   deleted the cells containing the data above the table
   headerrowrange. Instead, I placed a Text Box and used a formula to
   look at another sheet where the last connection time and status were
   now stored to supply the text for the text box.
3. I can now see that even this Text Box, which occupies no cell, causes a problem for Excel SQL.
4. Before posting my question here, I made a copy of the workbook and removed the text box and the rows above the table headerrowrange. I still got errors. I still got F1, F2, F3 etc as field names (per @FunThomas's suggestion).
5. Only after deleting these rows and the text box and then **resizing** the table (actually, the same range as before) did the Excel SQL recognise the proper field names. I was then even able (just for curiosity) to insert a blank row above the table headerrowrange, and the SQL still worked.
6. It seems to me that Excel retained in memory the old table definition and only by removing all data above the table headerrowrange and then resizing the table did it refresh that. Perhaps I should be less lazy in future and call the sheetname and range (table address) in the sql: maybe that would ignore data in cells above the headerrowrange?

@PanagiotisKanavos: I was originally trying to compare two tables (actual Excel Tables, not just ranges, hence they have Field Names), one in ThisWorkBook and another in a closed Excel workbook. SQL is the best way to do this. Having failed to get a left join to work between these tables (and this Question might now have revealed why that wouldn't work!) I decided to bring the data from the external workbook into ThisWorkBook and compare there. Then I was going to find the differences, store in a recordset (hence SQL) and then INSERT INTO the external workbook.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: You can use PowerQuery to select data from multiple tables and files, join and process them. SQL is the best way, but it's not used through VBA. The old SQL data functionality has been superseeded by Powerquery.

Comment: I'd love to be able to use Power Query, except that my organisation has locked down the use of such utilities. It's not standard desktop configuration. I need to keep to the basics so that this tool can be rolled-out to other users.

Comment: It's not a utility. It's a built-in functionality in Excel 2013 and 2016. It *is* the standard that replaced the data connection tools in previous versions. It was available as a free addin in 2010.

Comment: Nonetheless, my organisation has not rolled this out in the 2013 version